# patching crack in flagstone patio

Tags: floor, patio, sealing, crack, patch

My flagstone patio is developing cracks at the joints.  I would like to know how to patch/seal them to avoid water from sipping excessively into the ground. I understand patching is not a water proof method.

What product can be used?  How do match the color of the "grout"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Matching the colour can be hardest job, but hopefully it is a common colour at near by stores.  I would remove all of the loose/crack grout and redo.  The local stores should the proper sealing for that grout.

Answer (score 0):

Treat it like any other failing grout situation - use a grout saw (or possibly small chisels and a mallet or hammer for some of this) to remove the failing grout, and re-grout the whole thing (and *bam*, matching the color is solved.)

You could also choose to replace the grout with polymeric sand, which might be a bit more tolerant of seasonal movement of the stones, since the base is obviously not preventing all movement.

Comment: Removing everything on a large patio is a big job.  I only have cracks in a few places.  Further, I expect more cracks over time.  Thus I am looking for something to fill the cracks.  How can alter the color of polymeric sand?  Can it gets into the smaller cracks (1st picture)?